# IE11 CSS hover rule for list item not triggered

Tags: css, navigation, hover, internet-explorer-11

Horizontal navigation, written in CSS.

Expected behaviour: show sub menu when hovering main list items

Problem: IE11 ignores the hover rules for the list items

```
.desktop-header ul li > ul {
    background: #fff;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
    visibility: hidden;
    opacity: 0;
    min-width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    margin-top: 5px;
    left: 0;
    padding-top: 5px;
    display: none;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
}

.desktop-header ul li:hover > ul,
.desktop-header ul li:focus-within > ul,
.desktop-header ul li ul:hover,
.desktop-header ul li ul:focus {
    visibility: visible;
    opacity: 1;
    display: block;
}
```

jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/dauwrsm2/3/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears to be an issue with the `focus-within` selector. 
If you change your CSS to the following it works:

```
.desktop-header ul li:hover > ul,
.desktop-header ul li:focus > ul,
.desktop-header ul li ul:hover,
.desktop-header ul li ul:focus {
    visibility: visible;
    opacity: 1;
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: This! Not sure why this breaks IE but it helped. Sometimes it can be so easy, thanks!

Comment: @despecial The `:focus-within` class has [compatibility issue](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:focus-within#Browser_compatibility) with IE. You could mark James' answer as an accepted answer. It can help other community members in future in similar kind of issues. Thanks for your understanding.